# Dollar sign in HTML attribute name

Tags: html, polymer

I was looking at some Polymer code ([link](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-media-query/blob/master/demo/index.html)) and stumbled upon something new to me: a dollar sign $ in an html attribute name e.g.

```
<div class="item" wide-layout$="{{wide}}">
```

Also, a CSS selector is used:

```
.item[wide-layout] .title { ... }
```

How is the $ sign interpreted in the element attribute ?

Thanks for your time folks!

Comment: hmmm, I just found out that it is a Polymer thing ( https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding ) and I was looking for an answer in the HTML specs !

Comment: At this point: `<div class="item" wide-layout$="{{wide}}">` wide is a variable, can change dynamically, so its attribute name has `$` at the end like `wide-layout$`  there are another use case at polymer like `this.$.{ElementIdName}.callSomeFunction();`  At this point calls a functions belong to the elements at the id name which is coming after $ sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `$` on the element *binds* a property to an attribute. You can read more [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding).

`wide` in your scenario is probably a `Boolean` property on the element.

When `wide = true`, a `wide-layout` DOM attribute will be added to the element so it can be targeted via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign tells Polymer that some code will change the attribute, may it be `class` or any specific property on a Polymer element.

The code can be a function or a simple variable.

```
Example:

<shopping-cart class$="[[colorDependingOnItem(onSale, typeOfBrand)]] row-element">
```

So the class can now change dynamically depending on what the method `colorDependingOnItem` returns, based on the two properties `onSale` and `typeOfBrand`.